# #1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql

Unable to create the tables due to

## 1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

what's the problem in here?
is it a syntax error or logical error?
and when i omit the foreign key constraint line it works fine.

```
create table classroom
    (building       varchar(15),
     room_number        varchar(7),
     capacity       numeric(4,0),
     primary key (building, room_number)
    );
create table department
    (dept_name      varchar(20), 
     building       varchar(15), 
     budget             numeric(12,2) check (budget > 0),
     primary key (dept_name)
    );

create table course
    (course_id      varchar(8), 
     title          varchar(50), 
     dept_name      varchar(20),
     credits        numeric(2,0) check (credits > 0),
     primary key (course_id),
     foreign key (dept_name) references department
        on delete set null
    );

create table instructor
    (ID         varchar(5), 
     name           varchar(20) not null, 
     dept_name      varchar(20), 
     salary         numeric(8,2) check (salary > 29000),
     primary key (ID),
     foreign key (dept_name) references department
        on delete set null
    );

create table section
    (course_id      varchar(8), 
         sec_id         varchar(8),
     semester       varchar(6)
        check (semester in ('Fall', 'Winter', 'Spring', 'Summer')), 
     year           numeric(4,0) check (year > 1701 and year < 2100), 
     building       varchar(15),
     room_number        varchar(7),
     time_slot_id       varchar(4),
     primary key (course_id, sec_id, semester, year),
     foreign key (course_id) references course
        on delete cascade,
     foreign key (building, room_number) references classroom
        on delete set null
    );

create table teaches
    (ID         varchar(5), 
     course_id      varchar(8),
     sec_id         varchar(8), 
     semester       varchar(6),
     year           numeric(4,0),
     primary key (ID, course_id, sec_id, semester, year),
     foreign key (course_id,sec_id, semester, year) references section
        on delete cascade,
     foreign key (ID) references instructor
        on delete cascade
    );

create table student
    (ID         varchar(5), 
     name           varchar(20) not null, 
     dept_name      varchar(20), 
     tot_cred       numeric(3,0) check (tot_cred >= 0),
     primary key (ID),
     foreign key (dept_name) references department
        on delete set null
    );

create table takes
    (ID         varchar(5), 
     course_id      varchar(8),
     sec_id         varchar(8), 
     semester       varchar(6),
     year           numeric(4,0),
     grade              varchar(2),
     primary key (ID, course_id, sec_id, semester, year),
     foreign key (course_id,sec_id, semester, year) references section
        on delete cascade,
     foreign key (ID) references student
        on delete cascade
    );

create table advisor
    (s_ID           varchar(5),
     i_ID           varchar(5),
     primary key (s_ID),
     foreign key (i_ID) references instructor (ID)
        on delete set null,
     foreign key (s_ID) references student (ID)
        on delete cascade
    );

create table time_slot
    (time_slot_id       varchar(4),
     day            varchar(1),
     start_hr       numeric(2) check (start_hr >= 0 and start_hr < 24),
     start_min      numeric(2) check (start_min >= 0 and start_min < 60),
     end_hr         numeric(2) check (end_hr >= 0 and end_hr < 24),
     end_min        numeric(2) check (end_min >= 0 and end_min < 60),
     primary key (time_slot_id, day, start_hr, start_min)
    );

create table prereq
    (course_id      varchar(8), 
     prereq_id      varchar(8),
     primary key (course_id, prereq_id),
     foreign key (course_id) references course
        on delete cascade,
     foreign key (prereq_id) references course
    );
```

Comment: Most of your tables have Foreign Key constraints. Which one is failing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like i have done, you have to add dept_name within brackets infront of the table name that foreign key references.
Eg:

```
create table course
    (course_id      varchar(8), 
     title          varchar(50), 
     dept_name      varchar(20),
     credits        numeric(2,0) check (credits > 0),
     primary key (course_id),
     foreign key (dept_name) references department(dept_name)
        on delete set null
    );
```

Comment: i have to add primary key of referenced table ?? or forign key index??

Comment: it has to be the column that you are referencing on the other table.In this case the dept_name in department table